# Swagger UI gives Cors error when requesting an endpoint

Tags: azure, cors, swagger, swagger-ui

I have small webapi application which I have registered in Azure and I want to login on Swagger UI page.
It seems that login succesful but requesting endpoints gives CORS error message back. Can anybody see what I am missing ?

[image]

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Name = "oauth2",
        Scheme = "oauth2",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {  "openid", "openid" },
                    {  "profile", "profile" }
                }                
            }
        }
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2" },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "oauth2",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            }, new [] { "openid", "profile" }
        }
    });
});
```

...

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.OAuthClientId(clientId);
        c.OAuthClientSecret(clientSecret);
        c.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
        c.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
    });
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I have created sample web Api project and added CORS configuration in below code:

**program.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    var configuration = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");

    var tenantId = configuration["TenantId"];
    var clientId = configuration["ClientId"];
    var clientSecret = configuration["ClientSecret"];

    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Name = "oauth2",
        Scheme = "oauth2",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {  "openid", "openid" },
                    {  "profile", "profile" }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2" },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "oauth2",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            }, new [] { "openid", "profile" }
        }
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

// Allow CORS
app.UseCors(options =>
{
    options.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowAnyMethod();
});

app.UseAuthorization();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        string clientId = null;
        c.OAuthClientId(clientId);
        string clientSecret = null;
        c.OAuthClientSecret(clientSecret);
        c.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
        c.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
    });
}

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "ClientSecret": "firstsecret",
    "ClientId": "your-client-id",
    "TenantId": "your-tenant-id"
  }
}
```

The above code executed successfully. check below:

[image]

After clicking on authorize button getting and by using client id able to authorized successfully. check below:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]